# Proper way to layout 2 blocks of items

Tags: qt, qml

I am having some problems with objects layout. 
What I need is to create 2 blocks of text items. Second block should follow first.
Here is my code:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

Window
{
    visible: true
    id: page
    Rectangle
    {
        id: contentRec
        anchors.fill: parent

        ColumnLayout
        {
            spacing: 16

            anchors.fill: contentRec
            anchors.margins: 16

            Rectangle
            {
                id: hlpRec
                color: "#fff"

                ColumnLayout
                {
                    anchors.fill: hlpRec
                    spacing: 8

                    Text
                    {
                        text: "Some text 1"
                        color: "#434D56"
                    }

                    Text
                    {
                        text: "Some text 1"
                    }

                    Text
                    {
                        text: "Some text 2"
                    }

                    Text
                    {
                        text: "Some text 3"
                    }

                    Text
                    {
                        text: "Some text 4"
                    }
                }
            }

            Rectangle
            {
                Layout.preferredHeight: 16
            }

            Rectangle
            {
                id: infoRec
                color: "#fff"

                ColumnLayout
                {
                    anchors.fill: infoRec
                    spacing: 8

                    Text
                    {
                         text: "Status text 1"
                    }

                    Text
                    {
                        text: "Status text 2"
                    }

                    Text
                    {
                        text: "Status text 3"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that second block overlaps first. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: you should specify `height` and `width` properties of the `Rectangle` elements.

Comment: @ramtheconqueror the point is that I don't know the proper height because I want rectangles to take size of theirs children i.e. **minimum** size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both of your inner [`ColumnLayout`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-columnlayout.html) components are set to fit their parents, which have neither their width/height nor their anchor properties defined, hence their size is zero. Because those [`Rectangle`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-rectangle.html)s don't clip their contents, you see the items overlapping.

When working with [`Column`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-column.html) or [`ColumnLayout`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-columnlayout.html), the content height will be calculated from what you put in those containers. If you do it correctly, you can build pretty flexible and clever layouts without having to keep track of individual heights. However, you have to specify the other dimension by either setting the width property or the appropriate anchors. In case of [`Column`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-column.html) and [`ColumnLayout`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-columnlayout.html) you want to "snap" the component's width to fit the parent. At the same time you could leave the height unconstrained, allowing the item to grow vertically. Same goes for [`Row`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-row.html) and [`RowLayout`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-rowlayout.html) where the width will be calculated and you have to specify a certain height.

The solution in your case could be either based on [`ColumnLayout`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-columnlayout.html) or [`Column`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-column.html). Note that the hlpRec and infoRec were removed and the anchors of [`Column`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-column.html)/[`ColumnLayout`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-columnlayout.html) were set.

Via [`ColumnLayout`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-columnlayout.html):

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

Rectangle {
    anchors.fill: parent

    ColumnLayout {
        spacing: 16

        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 16

        ColumnLayout {
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.right: parent.right
            spacing: 8

            Repeater {
                model: 5
                Text {
                    text: "top " + index
                }
            }
        }

        Rectangle {
            Layout.preferredHeight: 16
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.right: parent.right
            color: "#ff00ff"
        }

        ColumnLayout {
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.right: parent.right
            spacing: 8

            Repeater {
                model: 5
                Text {
                    text: "bottom " + index
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Via [`Column`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-column.html):

```
import QtQuick 2.6

Rectangle {
    anchors.fill: parent

    Column {
        spacing: 16

        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 16

        Column {
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.right: parent.right
            spacing: 8

            Repeater {
                model: 5
                Text {
                    text: "top " + index
                }
            }
        }

        Rectangle {
            height: 16;
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.right: parent.right
            color: "#ff00ff"
        }

        Column {
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.right: parent.right
            spacing: 8

            Repeater {
                model: 5
                Text {
                    text: "bottom " + index
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The [`ColumnLayout`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-columnlayout.html) will center content items individually and uses the total height available from the window whereas the [`Column`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-column.html) will align all elements from top to bottom using only the content height. You'll notice the different behavior when changing your window's height.

In case those [`Rectangle`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-rectangle.html)s are used to define individual backgrounds, you can do something like this (demonstrated with the [`Column`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-column.html) based approach):

```
import QtQuick 2.6

Rectangle {
    anchors.fill: parent

    Column {
        spacing: 16

        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 16

        Rectangle {
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.right: parent.right
            height: topColumn.height

            color: "#ff0000"

            Column {
                id: topColumn

                anchors.left: parent.left
                anchors.right: parent.right
                spacing: 8

                Repeater {
                    model: 5
                    Text {
                        text: "top " + index
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Rectangle {
            height: 16;
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.right: parent.right
            color: "#ff00ff"
        }

        Rectangle {
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.right: parent.right
            height: bottomColumn.height

            color: "#0000ff"

            Column {
                id: bottomColumn

                anchors.left: parent.left
                anchors.right: parent.right
                spacing: 8

                Repeater {
                    model: 5
                    Text {
                        text: "bottom " + index
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: wow that is the best answer I got ever :) I moved first examle to my project and it works! Can you explain me the difference between Column and ColumnLayout? In which situations should I use Column and when should I use ColumnLayout? Is there a proper Qt book?

Comment: I'm glad I could help! Check out the [QmlBook](http://qmlbook.github.io), it's awesome! The difference between Column and ColumnLayout is basically the ability to use the [Layout](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-layout.html) attached property inside child-items. But you can achieve the same with both.